# React will not create a new nested component as expected

Tags: reactjs

In my application I have a page change mechanism that uses one of the properties of  parent component state.

So I do something like:

```
class mainComponent{
  state={
    mypage:null
  }

  onclickhandler(page){
    this.setState({mypage:page});
  }

  render(){
    return <div>{page}</div>
  };
}
```

In my "page" property I have various input fields and other components.

When I change the page, all inputs get updated with new values. However, my custom nested components are never re-created.

Instead, reach just calls `componentDidUpdate` on them.

Is there a way to force it to construct a new nested component somehow?

Comment: Shouldn't  `onclickhandler(page){` be like  `onclickhandler = (page) =>  {`?

Comment: Plus I guess state can't have `;` , it should probably be like  `state={
         mypage:null
       }`( without `;`)

Comment: There is just so much wrong with your code.
You are having  `mypage` in state and then you are doing `this.setState(page)` in your handler, You should probably do something like this `this.setState({mypage: page})` Also What is `page` when you did something like this  `<div>{page}</div>`?

Comment: i corrected those typos... question is still relevant

Comment: Just a suggestion, set the initial state inside a constructor. Have a look at [this part of the official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)

Comment: @c-chavez What is difference between setting the state inside the constructor and  outside the constructor (like the one op have done)

Comment: there is too many missing details, create [mcve]

Comment: @AnKing Your `custom nested components are never re-created` because reacts compares your current DOM with virtual DOM and this is what perhaps makes it faster. Why would your want to re-create everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React won't recreate component when it's not needed - it's a part of optimizations and general way react works.

When 'new', 'expected' component exists (the same type, the same or no `key` id) it only receives updated props.

Updating props **sometimes** doesn't force rerendering (it's guaranteed for state updates). `PureComponent` compares props shallowly, you can check `shouldComponentUpdate` (should return true to force render).

Comment: How can you `use componentShouldUpdate` to force re-render?

Comment: I ended up using key to re-render the internal components. Thanks for the solution!